# Hiding prices in WooCommerce for a set of products

Tags: woocommerce

In our Woocommerce products, we have two types of products.

- Products imported through script from a external XML url file.
- Products added as usual through woo admin interface.

We have added a meta field to identify these imported products.

What is the best method to hide prices ONLY for these imported products?
I have tried by removing some woocommerce actions, but its affects all woo products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried by removing some woocommerce actions, but its affects all woo products.

Then you need conditional logic. This should get rid of the price display in the loop.

**EDIT** As pointed out in the comments, once you remove the action it is permanently removed for all ensuing products. So in light of that I have added an `else` statement that resolves this issue.

```
function so_32584641_remove_price_from_loop(){
    global $product;

    if( 'mycbgenie' == get_post_meta( $product->id, '_mycbgenie_managed_by', true ) ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price' );
    } else {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'so_32584641_remove_price_from_loop' );
```

And this should remove it from the single product page:

```
function so_32584641_remove_price_from_single(){
    global $product;
    $your_meta = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_your_meta_key', true );
    if( 'mycbgenie' == $your_meta ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'so_32584641_remove_price_from_single' );
```

Comment: I am sorry. It was working fine. But I found a glitch later in  this code.

Comment: Your script works very well for single item but not for loop function. The script line remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price' ); is not working even after conditional logic is false.

Comment: What I mean simply is that like imported products, the usual woo products is too behaves in LOOP function. Single product function is working with out any problem.

Comment: One more comment. The loop function works as expected on one scenario where if filter out for this particular product using layered navs or price filters.. Example: http://localhost:8080/wp/?min_price=263&max_price=333&product_cat=arts-entertainment-humor   But not working on this url http://localhost:8080/wp/?product_cat=arts-entertainment-humor

Comment: One more comment. Your script for loop function works on SHOP url too.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's been a long day, what are you asking me now? I just tested it locally and without the meta the `remove_action()` is correct and removes the price.

Comment: Wait I will upload it online for you to show the discrepancies.

Comment: Hi,

My intention is to hide prices ONLY for the imported products via script to the Woo database. 
At the same time, i wish to display price for the products that are added through woo admin interface.
I have added a meta key with the value='mycbgenie' to identify the imported products.
Please look at http://www.cb4bucks.com/wp/product-category/arts-entertainment/arts-entertainment-magic-tricks/
There ar 13 imported products and one admin added product.
You can see a product which do not have a thumbnail, is the one that i have added through admin interface.

Comment: Your script would have been correct if these 13 products hide price but not the added one.
Here i can see all 14 products hide the prices.
If you click on that particular product, it shows price. That means your script works for the function
'so_32584641_remove_price_from_single()'. But it does not work for the function
so_32584641_remove_price_from_loop().

Comment: Well since your question didn't include a meta key name or the desired value to check against my code is more of a suggestion. You should change the conditional logic to `if( $your_meta == 'mycbgenie' )`. If that doesn't work I'd also switch the `$post` to $product`. I can't imagine how that'd make much of a difference, but just in case.

Comment: function mycbgenie_remove_price_from_loop(){

    global $product;
    $managed_by = get_post_meta( $product->id , '_mycbgenie_managed_by', true );
 
    if( $managed_by == 'mycbgenie' ){
  
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price' );
    }
 
}

Comment: Even this code is not working....... function mycbgenie_remove_price_from_loop(){

   // global $product;
 global $post;
   
 echo "Post/Prod ID : ". $post->ID;

    if ((int)$post->ID == 5591 )
         remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price' );
 
}

Comment: The above script can be checked on http://www.cb4bucks.com/wp/product-category/arts-entertainment/arts-entertainment-magic-tricks/page/5/

Comment: The problem with the above code is that it hides for product id 5591 and for the next product also.. I have increased the number of products per page to 12, then all products listed after product ID:5591 is also following the characteristics. I mean the remainng products after 5591 of that page is not showing the price. But it works fine if we navigates to next page.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now. I think we have to add the action back. Let me think about that for a bit.

Comment: Check my edit. You can see the result now in my [sandbox](http://sandbox.kathyisawesome.com/)

Comment: The patch worked like a breeze...Thanks for your timely help.